# How to run the program with attribute in WHERE

Tags: batch-file, search, cmd, exe, windows-7-x64

I need to search and run the program in cmd windows 7.  I tried the following code it doesn't seems to pickup the operator when key in together.

```
START WHERE /R C:\ Program.exe /uninstall
dir /s /b Program.exe /uninstall
```

Is there another (simpler/better) way to start the program with the operators?

Comment: Why would it work?

Comment: The program install in different directories in different PC and I need to search and initiate the uninstall. So far It was able to locate the file and launch it. It ignored the "/uninstall" which I usually type in cmd C:\location\program.exe /uninstall to delete the program.

Comment: Apology, I did not realized that the search function is not running the program. My bad. Is there any way to run the program via search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`where` searches files, but does not execute them. `start where` does nothing but starting `where` in a new `cmd` instance, so `start` relates to `where` but not to the file searched by `where`.

`dir` lists directory contents, but does also not execute anything. Actually you should use `dir /S /B C:\Program.exe` to search `C:\` for `Pogram.exe`; note that `dir /S /B Program.exe` searches `Program.exe` in the current working directory (recursively).

The `/uninstall` switch is considered as part of the `where` or the `dir` command line as you stated it.

You need to split your task into two phases:

1. searching for the file `Program.exe` in `C:\` recursively;
2. executing the file `Program.exe` using the option `/uninstall`;

Here is how it could work using `where`:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%E in ('where /R "C:\" "Program.exe"') do (
    "%%E" /uninstall
)
```

Here is a way using `dir` (the `/A:-D` option has been added to not return *directories* called `Program.exe`):

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%E in ('dir /S /B /A:-D "C:\Program.exe"') do (
    "%%E" /uninstall
)
```

If there are more files called `Program.exe` in `C:\`, all of them are executed.

Comment: maybe worth to mention: `where` looks only in folders within the `%path%` and therefore is quite fast. `dir` will search the whole folder tree down (the whole drive with `dir /s /b c:\program.exe`), which also gets findings outside `%path%`, but  may take a cup of coffee or two on a big, full drive...

Comment: @Stephan, the OP used the `/R` option of `where`, so `dir` and `where` are equivalent in this situation...

Comment: Thank you for the solution, would like to clarify how the C:\program.exe will search thoroughly in the C:\?  is it too if i want to search in C:\windows for program.exe is C:\Windows\program.exe?

Comment: If you specify `where /R "C:\WINDOWS" "Program.exe"` or `dir /S /B /A:-D "C:\WINDOWS\Program.exe"`, the file `Program.exe` will be found when it is located at `C:\WINDOWS` or any sub-directory, like `C:\WINDOWS\System32`, for example, but it will not be found if it is at `C:\TEMP`...